# webstorm ctrl-n for javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, webstorm

I use resharper and love it.  I use webstorm and love it too.  However, in resharper I can do ctrl-n and get a class, ctrl shift-n and get a file and ctl shift alt -n and get a method.

Well in webstorm which i"m using for javascript I would really really love it if I could say ctrl -somthing type DCI.Views.MyView and have it take to a backbone.js view ( or whatever the function may be ).
So for instance if I have a file that has

```
DCI.Views.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({ bla bla bla });
```

or

```
DCI.repository= (function(){ blah blah return blah blah blah}());
```

I would love to be able to navigate to those functions.
Any thoughts?
R

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it is exactly the same, but in phpstorm, you can hold down crtl and most of the objects and methods become clickable in the code. Often it says "multiple implementations" and will then give you a list of files where it is defined. Works fine with the js frameworks I use (like jquery, mootools and stuff).

Comment: right, and this is a great feature!  but the feature I'm looking for is, say I'm in some class and I think oh I need to go to some other class.  I can either go dig through the folder tree or go ctrl-n and type "someother class" and it will show me the matches. I click on one and it takes me to said class.   Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Have you tried to search by Symbol as described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/#Code_Navigation_and_Usages_Search)

Comment: yes, regrettably that will only take you to DCI not DCI.Views or DCI.Views.MyView.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to "Navigate By Symbol" as defined here: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html

```
Ctrl+Shift+Alt+N
```

This will list all symbols including JavaScript functions defined in a Backbone view. This is a project wide search which can sometimes be annoying when you want to only search within a specific view or class. Sublime has better navigation capabilities IMO.

The better option is to "Navigate with Structure Views": https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-with-structure-views.html

```
Ctrl+F12
```

With this type of search, it will directly search functions an properties defined on you currently opened view or class!!!

In addition, you can go to View > Tool Windows > Structure (or type ALT + 7) to see the Structure View of the currently opened file. This is a great navigation tool.